# Using a fresh apikey for Here Maps API v3.1, I got an error "apikey invalid. apikey not found"

Tags: javascript, here-api

I am trying to use the api of Here Maps version 3.1, especially the geocoding service.

I have followed the steps to have an api key, and then I tried to have access to the geocoder service using the example code of the [documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics/geocoding.html).

I replaced `{YOUR_API_KEY}` by my new apikey, and put the example code into a fresh index.html file :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script
      src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js"
      type="text/javascript"
      charset="utf-8"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-service.js"
      type="text/javascript"
      charset="utf-8"
    ></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="mapContainer"></div>

    <script>
      // Instantiate a map and platform object:
      var platform = new H.service.Platform({
        apikey: "MY_API_KEY"
      });
      // Retrieve the target element for the map:
      var targetElement = document.getElementById("mapContainer");

      // Get default map types from the platform object:
      var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();

      // Instantiate the map:
      var map = new H.Map(
        document.getElementById("mapContainer"),
        defaultLayers.vector.normal.map,
        {
          zoom: 10,
          center: { lat: 52.51, lng: 13.4 }
        }
      );

      // Create the parameters for the geocoding request:
      var geocodingParams = {
        searchText: "200 S Mathilda Ave, Sunnyvale, CA"
      };

      // Define a callback function to process the geocoding response:
      var onResult = function(result) {
        var locations = result.Response.View[0].Result,
          position,
          marker;
        // Add a marker for each location found
        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
          position = {
            lat: locations[i].Location.DisplayPosition.Latitude,
            lng: locations[i].Location.DisplayPosition.Longitude
          };
          marker = new H.map.Marker(position);
          map.addObject(marker);
        }
      };

      // Get an instance of the geocoding service:
      var geocoder = platform.getGeocodingService();

      // Call the geocode method with the geocoding parameters,
      // the callback and an error callback function (called if a
      // communication error occurs):
      geocoder.geocode(geocodingParams, onResult, function(e) {
        alert(e);
      });
    </script>
    <style>
      #mapContainer {
        width: 100%;
        height: 300px;
      }
    </style>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I open this file in my browser I can see the map with city names and everything so I think I have permission to access the map api, but the geocode service fails with a 401 error : `{"error":"Unauthorized","error_description":"ApiKey invalid. ApiKey not found."}`

But my apikey is enabled in my project page, I have checked and i didn't mispell the apikey (i copied/pasted it many times to be sure).

Do you have any suggestion ?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, could you try to create a new API KEY and test it again?

Comment: Hi, I have tried 3 keys and it didn't work, but strangely yesterday it started to work... I don't know why because i didn't change anything

Comment: It's good to work!

Answer (score 1):

While adding ApiKey always keep in mind to remove extra space before and after the key and also remove the {}.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/dev_guide/topics/geocoding.html

Answer (score 0):

Same issue for me. Then I created a new API key, and it's working with this one. Seems like a problem on HERE's end.